# Uploading image into ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble uploading an image into with a form through Django. The file does not appear in my `templates/auctions' directory, nor does it render in my template (probably because it never uploaded).

In my `views.py`:

```py
@login_required(login_url="login")
def createListing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        filled_form = CreateListing(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if filled_form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
            
            new_listing = filled_form.save(commit=False)
            new_listing.listed_by = user
            new_listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            context = {
        "createlistingform": filled_form
    }    
    else:
        context = {
            "createlistingform": CreateListing()
        }

    return render(request, "auctions/createlisting.html", context)
```

I tried to replicate the approach in ["Handing uploads with a file"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) and it's still not working.

My `AuctionListing` model in `models.py` has this field:

```py
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="images/")
```

and my project file `settings.py` has this configuration:

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Is my `commit=False` in the `views.py` creating an issue?

Comment: I see, I made sure to populate my `listed_by` field with a `User` model in 'views.py` and you're suggesting I need to do the same for my `image` field since I have the field option `blank=True` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you shared,

*Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST, at least one file field was actually posted, and the  that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.*

Also use commit = False when you get most of your model data from a form, but need to populate some null=False fields with non-form data.

Comment: Apparantly my `request.FILES` has no keys, so theres no way to manually populate the `image` field.

Comment: Done multipart/form-data part?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, my form in `createlisting.html` was missing the encoding type.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'createlisting' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ createlistingform }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This fixed the problem!